# Is there a pause button?

Tags: defcon

There is no pause button in the game speed bar. I have seen discussions where people mention <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>0</kbd> as the pause key except you have to turn it on. Neither of these work, and I have checked the menu looking for them but there is nothing.

**Is there a pause button in DEFCON?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

When setting up a new game, go into the `Advanced Options` tab.

Select the dropdown menu from `Slowest Speed`. When you set it to `Pause`, you will be able to pause the game by pressing <kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]